# Basic strength of nitrogen

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

What is the order of basic strength of nitrogens in the compound given in the figure?

$$\ce{
H2\overset{.\!\!.}{\underset{(γ)}{N}}-\overset{.\!\!.}{\underset{(β)}{N}}H-\overset{\overset{\huge O}{||}}{C}-\overset{.\!\!.}{\underset{(α)}{N}}H2
}$$

The most basic is the γ-N since its lone pair can't go in conjugation. My doubt is between α and β nitrogens, whose lone pair can go in conjugation.

Comment: For comparison between the alpha and beta nitrogen atoms, you may want to refer to the alpha effect: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_effect

Answer (score 2):

Tang Yong Boon certainly is in the correct direction (please refer to his comment).

I'll just wrap things up: 
$$\gamma > \beta > \alpha $$
$$\mathrm{(Basic \ strength)}$$

Reasoning:

- The $\gamma$ nitrogen is unquestionably the strongest basic site.
- $\beta$-nitrogen follows, as its tendancy of lone pair donation is greatly enhanced due to the presence of an adjacent (ie. alpha wrt. itself) electron donating group ($\ce{-NH2}$), otherwise known as the [alpha effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_effect). Some explainations include destabilization and elevated energy of the ground state, resulting in lower activation barrier.
- The $\alpha$-nitrogen is best called an acidic site.